# iPhone 5 won't load images from server

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiimageview, iphone-5

I'm stumped, I feel stupid, please help me.

I am fetching a list of wallpaper objects via JSON.  These wallpapers have image URLs that I load asynchronously into a grid view.  All good. An example image URL is the following:

http://url.com/desktops/desktops/2012/10/05/beach_iphone_thumb.png

iPhone 4 Simulator: works.  iPhone 5 Simulator: works.  iPhone 4 Device: works.  iPhone 5 Device: **DOES NOT WORK**.  What am I doing wrong?  The request's response error on the iPhone 5 device contains the following, yet the response's statusCode is 200:

```
Error Domain=com.mysite.error Code=-1016 "Expected content type {(
    "image/x-icon",
    "image/ico",
    "image/jpeg",
    "image/png",
    "image/tiff",
    "image/gif",
    "image/x-bmp",
    "image/x-xbitmap",
    "image/bmp",
    "image/x-win-bitmap"
)}, got text/html"
```

I'm using AFNetworking+UIImageView category to handle the image loading, but I would not think this would be the problem considering it works on both simulators and the iPhone 4 device.  Does anyone have any ideas?  Do I need to append something to my image name to make the iPhone 5 recognize it? Thanks!

Comment: If the exact same request is doing something different on the iPhone 5 hardware than on other hardware and the simulator, there's a good chance the web server is behaving differently due to something in the request. Perhaps it's sniffing User-Agent. You could use remote packet capture to see the actual response to your iPhone 5. http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#qa/qa1176/_index.html

Answer (score 1):

I tried loading it, and got redirected to a HTML page. That's consistent with the `Expected content type ... got text/html` response. If you know you aren't being redirected and the image is still not loading, check the response headers (Terminal command)

```
$ curl -I http://url.com/desktops/desktops/2012/10/05/beach_iphone_thumb.png
```

I get:

```
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Server: nginx/1.0.10
Date: Thu, 11 Oct 2012 01:15:30 GMT
Content-Type: text/html
Content-Length: 185
Connection: keep-alive
Location: http://search.url.com/desktops/desktops/2012/10/05/beach_iphone_thumb.png
```

Comment: Thank you; going to visit with my server dev and see if we can fix the issue. :)

Comment: The issue isn't the URL, the URL above was just an example.  Assuming the URL works, IE I get a 200 OK image/png back from a curl request, I still am not seeing the images on iPhone 5 devices!